# Does minhag hamakom apply to a college minyan?

Tags: halacha, minhag, nuschaot, minyan, college-university-school

At my university our minyan davens nusach Ashkenaz. Recently some have expressed the desire to allow the shatz to daven nusach Sefard, under the logic that since there are basically no permanent members of the minyan (since we all graduate eventually), maybe we don't have a minhag hamakom. Is that a valid argument?

Comment: Lucky for you we have an expert in MIT minyan Gabbai Emeritus here on site. [Paging @IsaacMoses...]

Comment: Malper, I'm glad to hear that minyanim are still running at MIT. :) To resolve your particular situation practically, I recommend that you consult the minyan's designated rabbi, possibly using anything you learn here as an input to the conversation.

Comment: Somewhat related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/7578 and http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/30344

Comment: See *T'shuvos v"Hanhagos* ([vol. 4, § 29](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=20027&st=&pgnum=29)), where R' Shternbuch implies that there should be no restrictions on the *sh'liach tzibur* in a *shtiebel* whose attendees represent a hodge-podge of *nuscha'os*, unlike in a place with a fixed *minhag*. However, it sounds like the members of this *minyan* are both relatively fixed (over a given time period) and mostly Ashkenazim. I suspect that, per [Isaac Moses' answer below](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/31985), the *minhag* of the *minyan* is sufficiently fixed.

Comment: Also, it's worth noting that we say m'ein sheva by Shabbos maariv and no one has objected to that. I don't know how similar the gdarim for that are though.

Comment: Just go up the street to Chabad! (of course I have run into you there)

Answer (score 3):

*The following is admittedly a weak and Aggadic answer. I've got a hammer, and if you squint right at this question, it looks kinda like a nail. I strongly suspect that a better answer could be found in actual Halachic sources.*

---

An essential difference between a community and an individual is that the community is "eternal," while individuals' lives are finite. This comes up, for example, in [R' Hirsch's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samson_Raphael_Hirsch) commentary on "[*Barechu*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barechu)" in [his *Siddur*](http://www.feldheim.com/the-hirsch-siddur.html). He points out that we require a [*minyan*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minyan), the smallest unit that can be called a community, to say "Blessed is the Lord, the Blessed One forever and ever," since the Jewish People (as represented by this community) can pledge to keep blessing God forever, while finite individuals cannot.

By that standard, no individual members of any community are permanent, and yet "permanent" communities persist. From the point of view of "eternity," it's hard to tell the difference between four years (or five or six or "oy, I've got to finish this dissertation already!") and 120.

Comment: [Temurah 15b](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=34&daf=15b&format=pdf)

Comment: @DoubleAA I think R' Hirsch may quote "the community doesn't die" from there. I'll check and [edit] when I have access to my copy.

Comment: Isaac, when you were at MIT, did they have a book of minhagim for the community? I know that up Mass. Av. at Harvard, OSM has a binder with printed copies of the minhagim, mainly in occasions where they differ from the trinity of Artscroll/Hirtz/Birnbaum.

Comment: @NoachmiFrankfurt No, we didn't have such a book. Our community was smaller and had many fewer long-term community members. We went on the immediate memories of participants, asking our rabbi (R' Segal in Newton), the Ezras Torah luach, and winging it.