# Which Tachanun should I say when davening in a minyan with a different Nusach?

Tags: halacha, minhag, tefilla, nuschaot, tachanun

I daven Nusach Ashkenaz but I often daven mincha in minyanim with a different nuasach.
Should I say my ashekanzi tachanun or is there a minhag ha'mokom?
Moreover I have noticed sefardim davening their own tachanun in my ashekanzi minyan.
If I can get Halachic sources that would be great!

Comment: related http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/1755/759

Comment: Are you asking about the text you should recite or the posture you should assume?

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya, user4526, and thanks for bringing your question here. You may wish to [change your username](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/edit/4526) (unless you're attached to the number 4526). I hope you stick around and enjoy the site!

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/30344

Comment: If you are already davening with a different nusach than the minyan why should tachanun specifically be like the minyan and not just your nusach?

Comment: would this also apply to differences even within Ashkenazi nusach or is your question specifically about differences between Ashkenazi and Sephardi nuscha'ot?

Comment: Sorry for the late response.
I heard from someone that I should say the same Tachunun as the Minyan. If I'm a Sephradi in an Ashkenazi minyan, I should say the ashkenazi Tachunun (not sure if that means posture, the text that I'm reciting or both) or if I'm a Ashkenazi in a Sephardi minyan vise versa.
Is this correct? Once again, any Halachic sources would be great!

Answer (score 3):

[Igros Moshe Orach Chaim 3:89 - last paragraph](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=919&st=&pgnum=398&hilite=) says that if ones Nusach is not to say Vidui & 13 Midos, and is in a Shul that does say Vidui & 13 Midos, he should definitely say the Vidui & 13 Midos. He says one has to follow the Minhag of the Shul he is Davening in, in any situation where it is noticeable.

[Rabbi David Lau](http://www.moreshet.co.il/web/shut/print.asp?id=58205&kod=&modul=15&codeClient=56) says that one who Daven's Ashkenaz, and finds himself in a Sefard Minyan should say his Ashkenaz Tachanun, however when the Chazzan says Vayavor you should say the 13 Midos with the congregation.

> אתה אומר את הנוסח שלך, אבל כשהחזן מכריז ויעבור, אתה אומר עם הציבור
>   את י``ג מידות

Comment: What if one's nusach is to say 13 middos and the minyan doesn't? Does he say them as davening or must he say them in the niggun (the way one is allowed to say them as an individual) -- this would not be noticeable and calls up the question of davening IN a minyan vs. WITH a minyan.

Comment: @rosends This question was regarding a person who Davens Nusach Ashkenaz and is in A Shul that Davens Nusach Sefard. You can [ask the question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) you have as  a separate question.

Comment: I started writing the question but hoped, after reading this that there was a generalizable rule.  I will try to formulate a question -- thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You must daven the tachnun according to the nusach you normally daven. The kitzur shulchan oruch says that one cannot chop and change nuschaos as they are all weighted and each word is counted. If you would like to add vidui before tachnun then that's okay, but you should try not say sephardic tachnun when davening in ashkenaz l'moshol. Rav Moshe Feinstein was very strict on staying with one's nusach.

Answer (score 0):

Rav Moshe Feinstein's rule of thumb is that for quiet portions of the davening, you have your choice of using your nusach or the minyan's. (Though the chazan's own quiet shmoneh esrei should follow what he'll say for the minyan five minutes later.) For parts that are public/out-loud, you should use theirs.

I haven't seen him address tachanun, so I would assume that you have your choice of what to say *quietly*; however if they're all standing when you're sitting or vice versa (e.g. nusach sefard starts with nefilas apayim on Mondays and Thursdays), I don't know what Rav Moshe would say.

Comment: can you please bring the reference to Rav Moshe Feinstein's rule?